# What code can I use in Python to convert 40,000 rows of latitude and longitude figures (which are in radians) into cartesian coordinates?

Tags: python, math

The table below is an example of the data I'm working with.

```
unimportant      latitude    longitude        lat         long
    a            52.927700    -3.243150     0.975123    -0.054621
    b            54.396837    -1.680645     0.959385    -0.029333
    c            52.902610    -1.473000     0.623323    -0.029691
    d            51.541824    0.081160      0.899576    0.000417
    e            51.073047    -0.423974     0.705355    -0.009382
                                  :
                                  :
```

I have a table with 5 columns and 40000 rows. 1 column is not important. Columns 2 and 3 shows 'longitude' and 'latitude' in degrees and columns 4 and 5 shows latitude and longitude titled 'lat' and 'long' in radians. I was tasked with adding 3 new columns x, y, z which show cartesian coordinates based on 'lat' and 'long'. I assume that z represents elevation however I'm not entirely sure how to calculate this.

How can I calculate x,y,z and add them onto the table?

I've already attempted to use the code shown in an answer given to a similar question on this site, however I get the TypeError: must be real number, not str error.

```
def Cartesian_coordinates(lat,long):
    R = 6371
    x = R * math.cos(lat) * math.cos(long)
    y = R * math.cos(lat) * math.sin(long)
    z = R * math.sin(lat)
    return x,y,z
```

Calling the function using

```
Cartesian_coordinates('lat', 'long')
```

Only yields

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Comment: You're calling strings not variables, try `Cartesian_coordinates(df.latitude, df.longitude)`

Comment: `lat` and `long` are strings not numbers. `cos(lat)`, `sin(lat)`, `cos(long)` and `sin(long)` do not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cartesian_coordinates(df.latitude, df.longitude)
```

You should put args as values not string
for example:

```
'df.latitude' - this is string
df.latitude - this is value with type of df.latitude
```

Answer (score 0):

You are *referencing* the Series' incorrectly: it should be - `Cartesian_coordinates(df['lat'], df['long'])`.

You might want to rework your function to operate on the complete Series:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'unimportant': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'},
     'lat': {0: 0.97512299999999996,  1: 0.95938500000000004,  2: 0.62332299999999996,  3: 0.89957600000000004,  4: 0.70535500000000007},
     'latitude': {0: 52.927700000000002,  1: 54.396836999999998,  2: 52.902609999999996,  3: 51.541823999999998,  4: 51.073046999999995},
     'long': {0: -0.054621000000000003,  1: -0.029332999999999998,  2: -0.029691000000000002,  3: 0.000417,  4: -0.0093819999999999997},
     'longitude': {0: -3.24315,  1: -1.6806450000000002,  2: -1.4730000000000001,  3: 0.081159999999999996,  4: -0.42397399999999996}      }

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['unimportant','latitude','longitude','lat','long'])

def Cartesian_coordinates(lat, long):
    R = 6371
    x = R * np.cos(lat.values) * np.cos(long.values)
    y = R * np.cos(lat.values) * np.sin(long.values)
    z = R * np.sin(lat.values)
    return x,y,z

x,y,z = Cartesian_coordinates(df['lat'], df['long'])
df['x'],df['y'],df['z'] = x,y,z


In [38]: print(df[['x','y','z']])
             x           y            z
0  3569.222097 -195.148591  5273.728439
1  3655.531649 -107.258474  5216.821349
2  5170.610116 -153.565713  3718.985023
3  3962.392411    1.652318  4988.896135
4  4850.547744  -45.509174  4130.345808

In [39]:
```

---

[Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#)